# PHP- Creating and image and reading it gives different values

Tags: php, image-processing

While working on the images in PHP, i noticed a strange behavior, not sure why.

I read a jpeg image, then create a new image from it. Then I read the new image. But, displaying the color values give different results. (Though, images look same.)

Here is my code:

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('test2.jpg');
imagejpeg($img, 'test100.jpg'); 
$new= imagecreatefromjpeg('test100.jpg');   
list($width,$height) = getimagesize('test100.jpg'); 

for($x=0; $x<$width; $x++){
    for($y=0; $y<$height; $y++){
        echo "At [$x][$y] --".imagecolorat($img,$x,$y)."--".imagecolorat($new,$x,$y)."<br>";
    }
}
```

I get the following output:

```
At [0][0] --14732734--14667454
At [0][1] --14601148--14666941
At [0][2] --13810862--13810862
At [0][3] --14271156--14139570
At [0][4] --15717832--15652039
At [0][5] --14598838--14401972
At [0][6] --11440262--11309188
```

And so on...

I'm not getting the why the values are getting changed, though images look similar.
Please help.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

JPEG is an image file format with [lossy compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression). That means you will loose data each time you save an image.

That you see different color values per pixel means nothing different than data-loss. Instead of opening and re-saving, just copy the jpeg file with the file-system functions

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('test2.jpg');
copy('test2.jpg', 'test100.jpg');          ## <-- copy image _file_
$new= imagecreatefromjpeg('test100.jpg');
```

you will then get the identical results:

```
At [0][0] --855561--855561
At [0][1] --855561--855561
At [0][2] --921353--921353
At [0][3] --987144--987144
At [0][4] --1052937--1052937
At [0][5] --1250570--1250570
At [0][6] --1579535--1579535
```

Comment: Thank You Hakre, but I can't copy the files. My main motive is to upload a pic over the facebook framework using a facebook app. Then, based on needs, i need to save the file from facebook database.

Comment: Well, as long as you open and save, this will always be different. That is the nature of a lossy image encoding like JPG. Try to save as PNG, at least the file format allow lossless saving when you choose highest quality (no idea if GD lib supports that, but why not?!).

Comment: I need to find something for JPEG format, as facebook converts every picture into jpg, even if i upload it as PNG. So, again, i get undesired different values. So far, no success.

Answer (score 0):

The quality of the image saved to test100.jpg would be default at 75% if no value is specified when saving... use the following to save 100% quality.

```
imagejpeg($img, 'test100.jpg', 100);
```